# Problems after update to OSX Catalina

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, macos

I recently updated my MacBook to OSX Catalina and now I am getting some unwanted behavior in vim (though it seems to be working overall?).

On opening vim I see the following stream of errors (NERDTree is open by default, I have a manually created vim system that is on the plug-in heavy side):

```
MacBook-Pro:project josh$ vi
Error detected while processing /Users/josh/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/nerdtree/path.vim:
line    3:
E121: Undefined variable: g:NERDTreeSortOrder
E116: Invalid arguments for function index(g:NERDTreeSortOrder, '*')
Error detected while processing /Users/josh/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim:
line    6:
E121: Undefined variable: g:NERDTreeFileNode
E116: Invalid arguments for function copy(g:NERDTreeFileNode)
line    7:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   11:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   12:
E121: Undefined variable: b:NERDTreeRoot
line   13:
E121: Undefined variable: currentNode
line   16:
E133: :return not inside a function
line   17:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line   20:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   21:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   22:
E121: Undefined variable: a:0
line   23:
E121: Undefined variable: self
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#renderView[12]..nerdtree#dumpHelp:
line    2:
E121: Undefined variable: b:treeShowHelp
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#renderView:
line   15:
E121: Undefined variable: g:NERDTreeMinimalUI
line   20:
E121: Undefined variable: b:NERDTreeShowBookmarks
line   25:
E121: Undefined variable: g:NERDTreeMinimalUI
line   31:
E121: Undefined variable: b:NERDTreeRoot
line   32:
E121: Undefined variable: header
E116: Invalid arguments for function setline
line   37:
E121: Undefined variable: b:NERDTreeRoot
line   38:
E353: Nothing in register o
Error detected while processing /Users/josh/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim:
line   25:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line   26:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line   34:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   35:
E121: Undefined variable: self
E116: Invalid arguments for function add
line   36:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line   38:
E121: Undefined variable: a:inOrder
line   41:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line   45:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   46:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line   47:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line   51:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   52:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line   58:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line   70:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   71:
E121: Undefined variable: g:NERDTreeFileNode
line   72:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line   73:
E133: :return not inside a function
line   74:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line   81:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   82:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line   83:
E121: Undefined variable: a:path
line   84:
E133: :return not inside a function
line   86:
E121: Undefined variable: a:path
E116: Invalid arguments for function stridx(a:path.str(), self.path.str(), 0) ==# -1
line   87:
E133: :return not inside a function
line   90:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line   94:
E133: :return not inside a function
line   98:
E133: :return not inside a function
line   99:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  103:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  104:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  105:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  115:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  116:
E121: Undefined variable: a:path
E116: Invalid arguments for function stridx(a:path.str(), self.path.str(), 0) ==# -1
line  117:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  120:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  121:
E121: Undefined variable: index
line  122:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  124:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  127:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  135:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  136:
E121: Undefined variable: a:visible
line  137:
E121: Undefined variable: a:indx
line  140:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  141:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  151:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  152:
E121: Undefined variable: a:path
E116: Invalid arguments for function stridx(a:path.str(), self.path.str(), 0) ==# -1
line  153:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  158:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  159:
E121: Undefined variable: z
line  168:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  171:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  172:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  177:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  178:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  179:
E121: Undefined variable: g:NERDTreeFileNode
line  180:
E121: Undefined variable: currentDir
line  185:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  186:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  190:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  191:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  192:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  199:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  201:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  206:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  207:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  211:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  212:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  213:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  223:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  225:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  228:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  229:
E121: Undefined variable: dir
line  232:
E121: Undefined variable: globDir
E116: Invalid arguments for function globpath(globDir, '*', 1) . "\n" . globpath(globDir, '.*', 1)
line  237:
E121: Undefined variable: filesStr
E116: Invalid arguments for function split(filesStr, "\n")
line  239:
E121: Undefined variable: a:silent
line  244:
E121: Undefined variable: files
line  261:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  263:
E121: Undefined variable: a:silent
line  270:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  271:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  278:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  279:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  280:
E121: Undefined variable: a:path
line  284:
E121: Undefined variable: self
E116: Invalid arguments for function copy(self)
line  285:
E121: Undefined variable: a:path
line  287:
E121: Undefined variable: newTreeNode
line  288:
E121: Undefined variable: newTreeNode
line  290:
E121: Undefined variable: newTreeNode
line  292:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  293:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  299:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  300:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  301:
E121: Undefined variable: a:0
line  303:
E121: Undefined variable: opts
E116: Invalid arguments for function has_key(opts, 'where') && !empty(opts['where'])
line  309:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  311:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  314:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  320:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  321:
E121: Undefined variable: a:0
line  324:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  325:
E121: Undefined variable: node
line  334:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  335:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  340:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  341:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  342:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  345:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  346:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
TreeDirNode.openInNewTab is deprecated, use open() instead
line  348:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  349:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  352:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  354:
E121: Undefined variable: self
E116: Invalid arguments for function 29
line  355:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  363:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  364:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  365:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  374:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  375:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  387:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  390:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  391:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  392:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  395:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  439:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  444:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  445:
E121: Undefined variable: a:path
line  449:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  451:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  455:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  458:
E121: Undefined variable: a:path
line  459:
E121: Undefined variable: p
line  463:
E121: Undefined variable: self
line  464:
E121: Undefined variable: n
line  465:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function
line  475:
E121: Undefined variable: s:TreeDirNode
line  476:
E121: Undefined variable: self
E116: Invalid arguments for function range(0, self.getChildCount()-1)
line  479:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  483:
E605: Exception not caught: NERDTree.ChildNotFoundError: child node was not found
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I press enter to continue, everything is fine although in subtle ways it looks different than before the Catalina update so I am guessing there was a vim version change or something.

Here is the output of `vi --version`:

```
$ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 29 2020 00:47:39)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-2292
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
-arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
-balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            -gettext           +num64             +textprop
+builtin_terms     -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        -vartabs
+clipboard         -keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            -profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      -langmap           +python/dyn        +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
-conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          -rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      -sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            -mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
-emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          -mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

I've had the same .vimrc and .vim directory for several (5ish?) years so it's likely updates to plugins might be part of the solution and hence why I thought this is question is not redundant to this one: [`:help` returns an “E432: Tags file not sorted” error](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22935/help-returns-an-e432-tags-file-not-sorted-error/22936#22936)

Would you recommend updating vim, updating NERDTree? Everything is working but the explosion or error messages seems worth fixing on its own.

Edit, with my `.vimrc`. Commenting out all NERDTree related lines did not work, moving the NERDTree directory out of `.vim/bundle` did remove the errors (but also removed the NERDTree functionality that I am hoping to preserve):

```
set nocompatible

" Pathogen
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

set statusline=%<\ %n:%f\ %m%r%y%=%-35.(line:\ %l\ of\ %L,\ col:\ %c%V\ (%P)%)
filetype plugin indent on

syntax on
set number
set hlsearch
set showmatch
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set nowrap
set autoindent
set history=1000
set cursorline
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4

" Nerdtree
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
let NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1
let NERDTreeChDirMode=0
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1
let NERDTreeMouseMode=2
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc','\~$','\.swo$','\.swp$','\.git','\.hg','\.svn','\.bzr']
let NERDTreeKeepTreeInNewTab=1
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_gui_startup=0


set background=dark
colorscheme wombat

inoremap jj <Esc>

nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;

" Strip trailing whitespace on Python, PHP, JS, SCSS, and CSS files
autocmd BufWritePre *.py :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.php :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.js :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.sass :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.css :%s/\s\+$//e

nnoremap \e :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

inoremap <C-l> <Esc>$a
nnoremap \l :setlocal number!<CR>
nnoremap \o :set paste!<CR>

" fix possible charset issue without changing charset
" let g:NERDTreeDirArrows=0

inoremap scc <Esc>m`A;<Esc>``i
nnoremap sc <Esc>m`A;<Esc>``

" More spaces for php
autocmd Filetype php setlocal ts=4 sw=4 sts=0 expandtab

" Strip Trailing Whitespace Function
" Usage :call TrimWhiteSpace()
fun! TrimWhitespace()
    let l:save_cursor = getpos('.')
    %s/\s\+$//e
    call setpos('.', l:save_cursor)
endfun
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of you vimrc? It looks like all errors seem to be related to the NERDTree plug-in. Can you try to disable it and see if they all go away? I looked at a recent git for NERDTree and didn't see the files in the location you reported here, so not sure if your NERDTree is too old or from somewhere else... ?

Comment: I added the .vimrc. I tried removing the nerdtree folder from .vim/bundle and it did stop the error messages (but also removed the plugin that I am hoping to use).

Comment: I tried checking out the most up-to-date version of NERDTree into the .vim/bundle directory and it appears to be working. It must have needed updating  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the solution was to upgrade NERDTree by running the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree
```

I also discovered why my helptags weren't working (a long term issue not asked about in the question), I had to run this:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/doc/
```

Thank you to @filbranden for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I also posted an answer. I'm suggesting vim-plug as an alternative to Pathogen which should help you keep plug-ins up to date. Hopefully you'll like the suggestion! 

Comment: Looks like I have a lot of updating to do, so I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your version of NERDTree was corrupted. It really looks to me that for some reason the `*.vim` scripts that were under `lib/nerdtree` inside the NERDTree plug-in directory ended up being moved to a `plugin/nerdtree` directory. Not sure if you can explain why this might have happened?

I see you're using Pathogen, which is OK, but it puts the burden on managing and updating plug-ins yourself.

I'll go ahead an recommend that you take a look at [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) instead.

The vim-plug manager is very similar to Pathogen in that it uses the same mechanism to manage plug-ins than Pathogen (updating `'runtimepath'` to list the base directories of plug-ins), but the advantage of vim-plug is that it can also install (`:PlugInstall`) and update (`:PlugUpdate`) your plug-ins for you. Which should help you keep them up to date. Or even reinstall them all from scratch if you need to.

Oh and vim-plug also takes care of indexing the documentation for the plug-ins it installs, so you don't need to deal with running `:helptags` manually for them.

Take a look at the README with installation instructions, also the FAQ of vim-plug. Hopefully you'll find it to be a suitable replacement for Pathogen and you'll also appreciate the features it brings to help you install and update plug-ins which are not available from Pathogen...